# Sci-fi film where an EMP device is used to disable an alien ship, and a huge robot rips through a gas station

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

I can't seem to find a film from the last 10 years which includes the following scenes.

One scene is where two guys drive out at night to test an EMP device to disable an alien ship from a distance, and it actually works!

Another scene is in an apocalyptic time on Earth, where a group of humans are on the run and get chased by a huge robot.  There is a gas station and they encounter another group of humans who try to rob them, but then this huge robot rips through the gas station.  Then they try to blow up the robot with a truck full of gasoline, but of course that does not work out.

These could actually be from different films.   :-)

Please help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is it possible that you're thinking of *[Terminator Salvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_Salvation)* (2009)...?

It definitely has a scene with a [giant Terminator robot](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Harvester) ripping through a gas station, and a failed attempt to blow it up with a gas truck.

There isn't strictly a scene with an EMP device being tested against an alien ship. However, there is a similar scene where a signal jamming device is tested against an [aerial Hunter-Killer](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/HK-Aerial), bringing it crashing down to the ground (and it is a nighttime scene, with two guys).

Comment: That was my first thought from that description, too.